# CMake is able to cross compile on 3rd invocation

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I've to cross compile a 3rd party library which uses CMake.

In order to build something, I need to pass "-B path" flag to compiler.

foo.c :

```
void main(){}
```

Build command :

```
cross-gcc -B /path/to/somewhere -o foo.o foo.c
```

Without "-B path" option, the compiler simply does not work.

Hence I use the following lines in my cmake toolchain file :

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")
```

But during the validation of compiler, CMake does not seem use the flags I set :

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /cross-path/cross-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /cross-path/cross-gcc -- broken
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "cross-path/cross-gcc" is not able
  to compile a simple test program.

....
....

/cross-path/cross-gcc -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
```

When I invoke CMake second time, cross-gcc passes the simple compilation test but this time cross-g++ fails :

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /cross-path/cross-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /cross-path/cross-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /cross-path/cross-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /cross-path/cross-g++ -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (MESSAGE):
  The C++ compiler "/cross-path/cross-g++" is not
  able to compile a simple test program.

....
....

  /cross-path/cross-g++ -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
```

And if I invoke CMake 3rd time, everything works fine with only a warning :

```
....
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
```

I'm using CMake 2.8.7 and aware that it is quite outdated but upgrade is not an option if this is the case.

Edit :

Toolchain file :

```
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /cross-path/cross-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /cross-path/cross-g++)
```

Comment: Can you show all the toolchain file that you used?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question.

Comment: I wonder if this is a case in which you should use the `CMAKE_FORCE_XXX_COMPILER()` macros, as you need to add those flags...have a look here [cmake_cross_compiling](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling) and look for `INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)`.

Comment: Exactly :) I used the method mentioned in the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476203/how-can-i-make-cmake-use-specific-compiler-and-flags-when-final-compilation-stag

Thanks very much for the tip. I'm not sure if you should add it as an answer or the question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: AH ok, I didn't see that SO, I just read the documentation I linked.... I will include these links (docs and this SO you mentioned) in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the problem of picking up the flags is very similar to one already discussed in SO in the past:
[CMake cross-compiling: C flags from toolchain file ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored)
Try the proposed solution, i.e. replace:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")
```

by

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

Try also to check if replacing your toolchain file with a new one that uses `INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)` as mentioned in
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling and
[How can I make Cmake use specific compiler and flags when final compilation stage instead of detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476203/how-can-i-make-cmake-use-specific-compiler-and-flags-when-final-compilation-stag) and
[Cmake cross compile flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045314/cmake-cross-compile-flags)

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-B /path/to/somewhere")

# specify the cross compiler
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(/cross-path/cross-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(/cross-path/cross-g++ GNU)  
...
```

has the same effect as the first hack. The second option seems a cleaner solution.